# Hide or disable Input Gesture Text in wpf

Tags: wpf

Say we're using "Ctrl+S" input gesture for saving the project.

In File menu - "Save         Ctrl+S" such text is displayed.
Now on canexecute of SaveCommand I check whether project required save or not. If it doesnt require then Save is disabled.

In that case I see menu item like "        Ctrl+S" . I've to hide this input gesture text also.

Ideas?

Any new feed ??

This question got no love :( ...

Comment: I need it v.soon. please come up with some good solution....

Comment: The menu item including the gesture text should be disabled automatically when CanExecute returns false.  Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: No. Input gesture text is disabled though but i want to make hide it too . I mean as "save" gets light grey or white color when it is disable but "CTRL+S" remains black. It seems to user that he can save the project by pressing keys although save is disabled.

Comment: Can you post some code to make your problem more clear to me?

Comment: Save menu item xaml :

<MenuItem x:Name="SaveMenuItem"
                      InputGestureText="Ctrl+S"
                      Command="{Binding FileSaveCommand}"
                      Visibility="{Binding MainApplicationVisibility}"
                      Header="{I18N:LanguageManager StringId=9720}" />

File Save Command has can execute which tell whether application needs save or not. If no save is required then "Save" text appears some what in white color (but visible) but the input gesture text i.e. "Ctrl+S" appears in black color same as it was earlier.

Comment: (so user thinks that he can actually save the application by pressing ctrl + s , although it doesnt happen as it is disabled.

Comment: I'm still waiting for any response ....

Comment: I think this should indeed be reported to Microsoft; even when set to `{x:Null}` it still shows the gesture, I want to get rid of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a fix. Overrided the default template of Menu Item and added a trigger that whenever Menu Item is disabled, change the color of Input Gesture Text to look like disabled.

Here is the overriden template and the last trigger does the above mentioned issue i mean color change..

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource SubMenuItemTextForegroundColor}"
            Background="{DynamicResource FileMenuBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                  SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                  SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                              Margin="6,0,6,0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              ContentSource="Icon" />
            <Border x:Name="Check"
                    Width="13"
                    Height="13"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Margin="6,0,6,0"
                    Background="#C0C0C0"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="#404040">
                <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                      Width="7"
                      Height="7"
                      Visibility="Hidden"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                      Stroke="#404040"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="{TemplateBinding Tag,
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource TagToRecognizesAccessKeyConverter} 
                                                   }"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                       Margin="5,2,0,2"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon"
                 Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsCheckable"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Check"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    TargetName="Border"
                    Value="{DynamicResource SubMenuItemMouseOverBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    TargetName="Border"
                    Value="{DynamicResource FileMenuBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="HeaderHost"
                    Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="#DDDDDD" />
            <Setter TargetName="InputGestureText"
                    Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="#DDDDDD" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```